# Update field from a button on Index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table named `meeting_times` with fields:

```
meeting_date_time
user_id
```

I want to update the `user_id` column for a meeting time by clicking on a button on the index page.

The page is setup like this:

```
October 30, 2012
   08:00 [Reserve button]
   09:00 [Reserve button]
```

I have tried:

```
<%= button_to "Reserve", meeting_time_path(meeting_by_timestamp(timestamp), :user_id => current_user_id), :method => :put %>
```

and it rails acts like it works, but the database doesn't get updated.

- `meeting_by_timestamp(timestamp)` is a helper method that does what it
  says.
- `current_user_id` is the `user_id` of the person logged in.

How can I setup `button_to` so that it updates the database?
Is there a better method then using `button_to`?

Comment: When you click on the button, what does your console log show, which controller/method is getting this call?

Comment: Add your `rails route`, `controller code` and `its params (from log)`. It would be better to know what is being done inside the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate method in your controller called `reserve`, create a route that takes 1 param, meeting and then use `reserve_meeting_time_path(meeting)`. `current_user` can be accessed within controller anyway, and this way you can make sure that `current_user` reserves meetings for themselves only.

In your routes.rb

```
resources :meeting_times do
  member do
     put 'reserve'
  end
end
```

In your controller:

```
def reserve
  @meeting_time = MeetingTime.find(params[:id])
  @meeting_time.update_attributes(:user_id => current_user.id)
  # or however you want to handle it here
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= button_to "Reserve", reserve_meeting_time_path(meeting_by_timestamp(timestamp)), :method => :put %>
```